# Encoding images to base64 can help bandwidth usage?

Tags: php, caching, base64, bandwidth

I have a big website that is using too much bandwidth. Because My Webside contains images with High Resolution. Im caching the pages for 6 hours to reduce db usage.

My question here arises.

If i encode the images to base64, and cache that images in my server as base64, can help to reduce my bandwidth usage ?

I'm open to all suggestions coming from you.

Thank you so much.

Comment: base64 encoding increases length of image - this will increase bandwidth

Comment: @Lashane Really ? What can i do about that images ?

Comment: actually - almost nothing, you can try to re-encode them with lower quality, try different settings, formats (jpg/png), check whether caching actually enabled, but if users download different images in high quality - they will use bandwidth according image's size and you cannot change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen as base64 won't help, and enabling compression won't help much, you could always use a content delivery network (CDN).

Chances are you can get a better deal using a CDN than your current service provider, but it really does depend on your current deal.

Personally, I use [Cloudflare](http://cloudflare.com). Along with their protection (which I don't really need) they cache certain types of requests, such as images.

If these images are static you should increase your `Expires` to years or even decades, but that will only affect returning visitors or caches. Cloudflare should take a significant load off your server. In some circumstances the load (bandwidth) on my server has been reduced by 50% - which is nice.

[image: Bandwidth saved last month]

Cloudflare has a free tier which I think you might be interested in.

Test everything thoroughly before using any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments --

No, Base64 encoding will not help your bandwidth usage. In fact, it will likely make it worse.

Comment: All right, another question ; Storing images in the database can help about bandwidth usage ?

Comment: @EmreY The web server accesses the DB, not the client. It won't make an iota of difference and will just make the server work harder.